# Empty Array after reading from Firebase in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, firebase, swiftui

I have class `getDataFromDatabase` which has func `readData` thats read data from Firebase.

```
class getDataFromDatabase : ObservableObject {

    var arrayWithQuantity = [Int]()
    var arrayWithTime = [Double]()
    
    func readData(completion: @escaping(_ getArray: Array<Int>?,_ getArray: Array<Double>?) -> Void) {
       
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        
        db.collection("amounts").getDocuments { (querySnapshot, err) in
            
            if let e = err{
                print("There's any errors: \(e)")
            }
            
            if err != nil{
                print((err?.localizedDescription)!)
                return
            }
            
            for i in querySnapshot!.documents{
                
                let quantityFromDb = i.get("amount") as! Int
                let timeFromDb = i.get("averageTimeRecognition") as! Double
                
                
                self.arrayWithQuantity.append(quantityFromDb)
                self.arrayWithTime.append(timeFromDb)
            }
            completion(self.arrayWithQuantity, self.arrayWithTime)
        }
    }
}
```

I use this func in `onAppear`:

```
struct CheckDatabaseView: View {
    
    @State private var quantityFromDatabase: Array<Int> = []
    @State private var timeFromDatabase: Array<Double> = []
    @State private var flowersName: Array<String> = ["Carnation", "Daisy", "Hyacinth", "Iris", "Magnolia", "Orchid", "Poppy", "Rose", "Sunflower", "Tulip"]
    @State private var isReady: Bool = false
    
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false){
            ZStack(alignment: .top){
                VStack(spacing: 40){
                    Text("Hello, world!")
//                    BarView(value: CGFloat(timeFromDatabase[0]), week: flowersName[0])
                    
                }
            }
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .top)
            
        }
        .navigationBarTitle(Text("Your datas in database").foregroundColor(.blue), displayMode: .inline)
        .onAppear{
            
            let gd = getDataFromDatabase()
            gd.readData { (quantity, time) in
                self.quantityFromDatabase = quantity!
                self.timeFromDatabase = time!
                
                for i in 0...5{
                    print("Quantity: \(self.quantityFromDatabase[i])")
                }
                
            }
            print("Quantity after reading: \(self.quantityFromDatabase.count)")
        }
    }
}
```

I need to get values from Firebase and use it in `VStack`, because I want to draw a chart.  To make this possible, I need to read the data from the database at the beginning and I do it in `onAppear`. Problem is with getting this values. I set two prints - first in using a `readData()`:

```
print("Quantity: \(self.quantityFromDatabase[i])")
```

and second when function was done:

```
print("Quantity after reading: \(self.quantityFromDatabase.count)")
```

The first print, shown correct values from Firebase, but second print shown empty Array. I have no idea why this is so. Why can't I use this data?

Comment: The function is **not** done when the second print line is executed. `readData` works asynchronously. Do the things you have to do in the same scope as the first print line: Inside the completion handler. And you are strongly discouraged from using multiple arrays as data source. Don't do that.

Comment: Hi @vadian thank you for your response. I need to get this data to draw a charts. Single chart is defined in ```struct BarView: View```, but I cannot use this in onAppear - I have to draw charts in ```VStack```. How should I create charts in the same scope as the first print? And thank you I will remember not to use multiple arrays.

Comment: Read the first comment again.